# Time Plot shows a bit of waiting time gap every third output (Production Rate)

Tags: anylogic

I am displaying output rate of production time pear hour. Every third output *there is a bit of waiting time that is different than waiting time between first and second output. I don't understand why every third output there is a different waiting time? * (Picture 1). Additionally, *the output on the Y axis is different than the output or input value from the source or Sink* (Picture 1 and 2). I am a bit confused with these issues. Further illustration below:

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

I have created a variable (hourOutput), data set (dataProductionRate) and event (productionRateCount) to calculate output rate. Time plot in picture 1 read data set value as output (dataProductionRate).

code used in event: `dataProductionRate.add( hourOutput );`

code used in Sink:

```
hourOutput++;
Hyber_Facadesink_V++;
agent.TimeOut = time();
variable++;

if(self.count()>=Gen_Item){
   
    getEngine().finish(); //to end the model execution
```

}

Comment: how did you setup the Ds and the chart? Auto-update or manual?

Comment: DS setup to Do not update data automatically  and Display up to 10

Comment: Chart setup to Do not update automatically and  Display up to 24

Comment: well then the problem is that you are updating the graph/dataset in uneven intervals

Comment: Thanks Felipe, So to update it evenly do I need to adjust the number of Recurrent time in Event.

Comment: The output still shows 8 not 9 in data set and on graph. Any reason for not showing the actual value (9)?